# NativeException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: null

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I have started Hadoop and Hbase successfully. But when I try this operation like,
./hbase shell
HBase Shell; enter 'help' for list of supported commands.
Version: 0.20.3, r902334, Mon Jan 25 13:13:08 PST 2010
hbase(main):001:0> create 'userstable', {NAME => 'maininfo'}, {NAME => 'additionalinfo'}
NativeException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: null

Any idea what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible to use a newer version of HBase.  While not specifically related to this error, there are many known problems that have been fixed in more recent versions.

Otherwise, as Nija said, check the master log to see what it says.  The logs should always be your first resource when you run into issues.

Answer (score 0):

The `MasterNotRunningException` is indicating that the HBase master is not running. What normally is the case for me when I encounter this are 2 things: I didn't start hbase, or there is more information in the logs pointing out something equally simple.

Did you run `$HBASE_HOME/bin/start-hbase.sh` (it's early and I don't have access to my install so the exact script name may be off) where $HBASE_HOME is the install path for hbase.

Check the hbase logs for more information on what is preventing the master from starting. (I still don't have access to my installs so don't remember exactly which hbase log)

If you need help with the info from the logs, update your post with the new information.